# Java Expression Language Projection for each element in collection get new Object of other type

Tags: java, expression, ognl, spring-el

I have below given scenario and problem , looking for someone to provide solution/suggestion.

Scenario: There are different types of business-beans objects, these business-beans do not having  common properties and cannot be generalized. For different task/job I have to deal with collection of business-bean  of one type. Out this collection I want another collection of `MyKey` type. The `MyKey` constructor is:
 `MyKey(String buzUnit, String id, String subId)` 
Corresponding to different business-bean the value I need for MyKey's constructor (`buzUnit`, `id` and `subId`) , is going to be different properties of business-bean that again depends on executing task/job .

I like to make it configurable based on task/job and maintain the configuration in database.

Problem:
I am trying to use any EL (OGNL, Unified EL, MVEL, SpEL) to achieve collection conversion. I tried using OGNL, but am not able to get desired result.

POC on OGNL:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new Point(2,3));
points.add(new Point(3,4));
points.add(new Point(4,5));

Map<String, Object> nameCtx = new HashMap<String, Object>();
nameCtx.put("buzBeanCollection", points);

Object retCollection = Ognl.getValue("buzBeanCollection.{new org.my.MyKey('job12', #this.x, #this.y) }", nameCtx);
```

In the above code `#this` is resolving into root HashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using MVEL.

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new Point(2,3));
points.add(new Point(3,4));
points.add(new Point(4,5));

Map<String, Object> nameCtx = new HashMap<String, Object>();
nameCtx.put("buzBeanCollection", points);

Object result = MVEL.eval("((new org.my.MyKey('job12', $.x * 2, $.y * 2)) in buzBeanCollection)", nameCtx);
System.out.println(result);
```

Other conclusion based in MVEL capabilities; I have found that OGNL's AST is created using ANTLR but MVEL has its own integrated Lexer-Parser, including Subparsers.

OGNL was not able to do simillar projection was that a problem of OGNL or problem with ANTLR ?

Comment: What is x and y in this